# Обнуляется счётчик при изменении в форме (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

в общем проблема такова, у меня есть форма на React JS в модальном окне, реализованая через Material UI.

```js
<RadioGroup aria-label="test" name="test" value={answer} onChange={handleChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value={test.a1[0]} control={<Radio />} label={test.a1[0]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test.a1[1]} control={<Radio />} label={test.a1[1]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test.a1[2]} control={<Radio />} label={test.a1[2]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test.a1[3]} control={<Radio />} label={test.a1[3]} />
                    </RadioGroup>
```

В ней, как можно заметить, есть `onChange` которая меняет `state`

```js
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
```

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
        setAnswer(e.target.value)
    }
```

И также, есть кнопочка, которая выполняет некоторую функцию `handleSubmit`

```js
<Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} color="primary">Submit</Button>
```

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
           if (answer == "") {
               alert("!")
           } else {
            qCount += 1
            console.log(qCount)
           }
    }
```

Ну и так же есть переменная `let qCount = 1`
По логике, при выборе одного из вариантов формы и нажатии на кнопку Submit, `qCount` должен увеличиться на 1 и вывестись в консоль.
Собственно в чём проблема, я выбираю один из вариантов, и нажимаю кнопку, всё идёт по плану и переменная увеличивается на 1, но стоит мне выбрать другой вариант и нажать кнопку снова, как счётчик обнуляется, и всё идёт сначала. То есть, пока одна метка radio активна, то кнопка работает, как только будет выбрана другая, счётчик обнуляется. Я думаю что в этом как то замешана функция `handleChange`, но как именно понятия не имею.

Вопрос: Почему так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qCount это не переменная а состояние по идее когда ты сделаеш

```
const [qCount , setQCount ] = useState(1)
```

по идее проблема должна исчезнуть. На счет проблемы

`setAnswer(e.target.value)`

setAnswer запускает перересовку и заново обновляется переменная let qCount = 1

Comment: Спасибо большое, это действительно работает и как я не додумался. Ещё раз большое спасибо.

Comment: @spectrum_10101 да не за что)